# Is it possible to bypass sql_color in Rails active record logs?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have an issue where a binary representaiton of an IPv6 address will cause the sql_color in active record logs to generate a very long error message.

The query does work and does return expected results.

I think this is because it the binary IPv6 looks like:

"\xFE\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\f"

And the sql_color method is interpreting that as control codes.

If I set:

```
Rails.applicaiton.config.colorize_logging = false
```

It still does it even though there is no longer any color being shown.

Ideally I would like to know the best way to bypass sql_color.

Right now I have just overridden the method and put it in a begin/rescue block.

**How to reproduce:**

```
   rails new binary_bug -d mysql
   cd binary_bug
   rails db:create
   rails g model Bug name:text first_ip:binary second_ip:binary
```

Update the migration to

```
 class CreateBugs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :bugs do |t|
      t.text :name
      t.binary :first_ip, limit: 16
      t.binary :second_ip, limit: 16

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
rails db:migrate
```

```
Bug.create(name: 'test1', first_ip: IPAddr.new('fe80::c').hton, second_ip: IPAddr.new('fe80::c').hton.to_s )
Bug.create(name: 'test2', first_ip: IPAddr.new('2001:db8:1234::').hton, second_ip: IPAddr.new('2001:db8:1234:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff').hton.to_s )
# Try to search the DB.
bugs = Bug.where("first_ip > ?", IPAddr.new('2001:db8:1234::12').hton)
```

This will give a very long error that starts with:

*Could not log "sql.active_record" event. ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8*

The first file it points towards is:

gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:71:in `sql_color'"

Which is a private method and looks like this:

```
  def sql_color(sql)
    case sql
    when /\A\s*rollback/mi
      RED
    when /select .*for update/mi, /\A\s*lock/mi
      WHITE
    when /\A\s*select/i
      BLUE
    when /\A\s*insert/i
      GREEN
    when /\A\s*update/i
      YELLOW
    when /\A\s*delete/i
      RED
    when /transaction\s*\Z/i
      CYAN
    else
      MAGENTA
    end
  end
```

If I replace that with just MAGENTA or wrap it in a begin/rescue block and restart spring it will work fine.